# Jboss Mail Service to lookup local mail server

Tags: java, email, jboss, jakarta-mail

How to send mail using JBoss Mail Service without the use of Javamail Transport.send().

I'm running local mailserver using jbms. I want to send mail using java program. Most of the search suggest to use javamail or mailservice.xml type.

I'll handle the EHLO, MAIL FROM, RCPT TO,... commands. I want to straightly call the DATA command. Is there any to call straight API request to call DATA command.

Is it possible to straightly call CMDData.java from the java program. Because the information related to the sender are available in local. I'll check whether the user is valid one or not.

Also I'll check recpt list with standard emailaddress format. I don't want to connect via secure port. As Its my local setup, there is no need for the secure setup.

Please help.

Comment: Is there some problem you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @BillShannon       
I'm using my local server. If I use Transport.send() it do lookup for the mailserver I have provided. That is going to be the same source Which i'm calling from. Also no need to do EHLO and other commands, as I'll validated in my code itself.

Comment: You can certainly configure JavaMail to use "localhost".  Optimizing away the use of EHLO seems like more work than it's worth, and a violation of the SMTP protocol.

Comment: @BillShannon  I use localhost in the name of the mail host. If I don't define port number it defaults to port 25. How to avoid that port in Transport.send() call

Comment: Set the mail.smtp.port property.  What port do you want to use?